# How to correctly count æ ø å (Unicode as UTF-8) characters in C?

Tags: c, unicode, character, counting

I am writing a simple program that counts characters from a textfile (UTF-8) that I put in a linked list. Everything seem to work well except that it counts æ ø å (three last characters in the norwegian alphabet) twice for each instance. So if the string is æøå, I get 6 instead of 3. How to fix this?

```
int length()
{
  pointer = root; // Reset pointer
  int i; // Looping through data in node 
  int len = 0; // Counting characters
  int sizedata = sizeof(pointer->data); // Sets size limit for data in node

  while(pointer != NULL)
    {
      for(i = 0; i < sizedata; i++) // Looping through data in node
    {
      if(pointer->data[i] == '\0') break; // Stops count on end of string
      len++; // Counting characters
    }
      pointer = pointer->next; // Linking to next node
    }
  printf("Length of text is: %d characters\n", len);
}
```

Comment: Is your text file in UTF-8? Then you should advance your characters according to their length in UTF-8. Only 7-bit ASCII chars take up one byte; the rest of the Latin1 chars take up two bytes.

Comment: Specifically, `c3 a6 c3 b8 c3 a5` would be the bytes needed for `æøå` (in case you weren't aware).

Comment: More important than how, is why. What is a 'character'? A glyph? A code point? If the latter, why count them? Why not count bytes? If not bytes, then glyphs? What are you trying to achieve? See http://utf8everywhere.org, how twitter counts characters.

Answer (score 1):

I changed the code according to this [site](http://www.daemonology.net/blog/2008-06-05-faster-utf8-strlen.html). Everything is the same expect for the `if` statement before `len++`;

```
int length()
{
    pointer = root; // Reset pointer
    int i; // Looping through data in node 
    int len = 0; // Counting characters
    int sizedata = sizeof(pointer->data); // Sets size limit for data in node

    while(pointer != NULL)
    {
        for(i = 0; i < sizedata; i++) // Looping through data in node
        {
            if(pointer->data[i] == '\0') break; // Stops count on end of string
            if ((pointer->data[i] & 0xC0) != 0x80)  //count characters
                len++;
        }
        pointer = pointer->next; // Linking to next node
    }
    printf("Length of text is: %d characters\n", len);
}
```

Note (thanks @Eljay):
This is counting Unicode code points (that are encoded in UTF-8), but not characters (glyphs). Some characters are made up of multiple code points. For example, x̝̌ is 78 cc 9d cc 8c, for the x and the two combining code points. This routine would count that 1 character as a length of 3 (code points).

Comment: This works, but keep in mind that it will not detect broken UTF-8 strings.

Comment: Thanks, the counting is now correct. But I don't really understand what ((pointer->data[i] & 0xC0) != 0x80) actually does. What does 0xC0 and 0x80 refer to here?

Comment: Please see the link posted.

Comment: This is counting Unicode code points (that are encoded in UTF-8), but not characters (glyphs).  Some characters are made up of multiple code points.  For example, `x̝̌` is `78 cc 9d cc 8c`, for the `x` and the two combining code points.  This routine would count that 1 character as a length of 3 (*code points*).

Answer (score 0):

Your text file seems to be encoded in UTF-8. Then you should respect the encoding length of a character, which can be derived from the first byte of a byte sequence, see [this Wikipedia atice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8).

The code below just counts the length of a single string, i.e. it does not make use of your linked list structure.

The length of a byte sequence is stored in an array for easy look-up; -1 marks an illegal value for a first byte in a sequence. The bytes marked `cont` are continuation bytes and should only occur after the first byte of a sequence in well-formed UTF-8 strings. Igor's solution, which is admirably concise in comparison to this one, just skips them.

I've cast the char pointer to a byte (or `uint8_t` in `<stdint.h>`), so that the array indices are guaranteed to be non-negative.

This solution is probably needlessly long, but may serve as a starting point when trying to decode the characters (as opposed to just counting them).

Anyway, here goes:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

static char utf8_len[256] = {
    1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,
    1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,
    1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,
    1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,
    1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,
    1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,
    1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,
    1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,
   -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,   /* cont */
   -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,   /* cont */
   -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,   /* cont */
   -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,   /* cont */
   -1, -1,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,
    2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,
    3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,
    4,  4,  4,  4,  4, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
};

/*
 *      Return character count of an UTF-8 encodes string; -1 indicates
 *      a decoding error.
 */
int str_length(const char *s)
{
    const uint8_t *p = (const uint8_t *) s;
    int len = 0;

    while (*p) {
        int cl = utf8_len[*p];

        if (cl <= 0) return -1;
        len++;
        p += cl;
    }

    return len;
}
```